# Split elements in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

My code is :

```
L=['my', 'my']
```

and I want to split the items of this list so that the output becomes:

```
['my'],['my']
```

each item in a new list

Comment: Can you clarify what the purpose of this is? For example, you are asking for 'output' but not specifying how you are attempting to output the result.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, use a list comprehension:

```
In [109]: L=['my', 'my']

In [110]: [[x] for x in L]
Out[110]: [['my'], ['my']]
```

or may you wanted this:

```
In [129]: print ",".join(str(x) for x in [[x] for x in L] )
['my'],['my']

In [130]: print ",".join("[{0}]".format(x) for x in L)
[my],[my]
```

Comment: I didn't get it , I am a beginner so please explain more 
Thank you!

Comment: I need each item to be separated from the main list 
I don't need the output like [['my'], ['my']]

Comment: I need it like that : ['my'], ['my']

Comment: @user1996764 you mean you want to print `['my'], ['my']`?

Comment: The result `[['my'],['my']]` has the items 'separated from the main list', they're just inside another list. The result `['my'],['my']` is two 'things' and needs to be containered to fit into a single variable. If you do `a=['my'],['my']` you'll end up with a tuple `(['my'],['my'])`

Comment: I know that I asked you a lot but I really appreciate your help 
your code does work but not the way I wanted 
I have a list which is 
lis=['my','name','is']

Comment: and I want to make an output like this:

Comment: ['my','name','name','is']
So is there anyway to edit the original list so that it becomes like that ?

Comment: @user1996764 this is completely different from what you asked, BTW what will be your expected output for `['my','name','is','foo']`?